# Node.js: how to get the URL to the page which called a POST from the request body?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am building an ExpressJS web application on Node.js.

I have a page that is rendered by GET a route: "http://localhost:3000/items/showItemList?status=0".

This page calls a POST: "http://localhost:3000/items/approve".

In the POST route I would like to get the URL to the URL to the originating page "http://localhost:3000/items/showItemList?status=0".

```
router.post('/approve', async function(req, res, next) {
  // How to get the Url to the originating page.
});
```

Comment: do you mean like a redirect when the POST is triggered back to the GET route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get from `req` param like this

```
req.headers.referer
```

Answer (score 1):

`const host = req.get('host')` or maybe `const origin = req.get('origin')`

used like this:

```
router.post('/approve', async function(req, res, next) {
  const origin = req.get('origin')
})
```

Comment: If its a redirect then it can be `return res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/items/showItemList?status=0');`

Comment: I don't think its a redirect. He's receiveing a POST request, maybe from ajax, and he wants to know the URL of the page sending the request

Comment: req.get('origin') gave me undefined while req.get('host') gave me localhost:3000. Both of them didn't give me the exact URL.